# Jenkins failing robolectric test cases...!

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I am trying to build my android project on **Jenkins 2.0** server on **Ubuntu** machine.

I am running the following commands for that purpose:-

1. ./gradlew clean (this  is working fine)
2. ./gradlew build (this is failing random number of test cases)

However I also install **Jenkins 2.0** on my **Windows 7** machine and run the same commands as above, and it was passing all test cases every time. I am not understanding what is wrong with that.

I did lot of debugging but could not find any solution, please help me to get rid out of this thing...!

This is my 34th build log on **Jenkins**

```
testPreCondition FAILED
    java.lang.NullPointerException at ConfigurationFragmentTest.java:36

handleBackButtonPressing FAILED
    java.lang.NullPointerException at ConfigurationFragmentTest.java:36

48 tests completed, 2 failed
:app:testDebugUnitTest FAILED
```

This is my 35th build log on **Jenkins** without making any code changes

```
    > handleBackButtonPressing FAILED
            java.lang.NullPointerException at ConfigurationFragmentTest.java:36

    > testPreCondition FAILED
            java.lang.NullPointerException at ConfigurationFragmentTest.java:36

      > testPreconditions FAILED
            java.lang.NullPointerException at UpdateTabFragmentTest.java:30

      > testPreconditions FAILED
            java.lang.NullPointerException at ServiceTabFragmentTest.java:29

      > testPreConditionIsNotNull FAILED
            java.lang.NullPointerException at HomeActivityTest.java:63
 48 tests completed, 5 failed
 :app:testDebugUnitTest FAILED
```

[image: This is one of the test class in which I am getting the error]

Answer (score 0):

You should check the Jenkins console output for something like
"WARNING: No manifest file found " in the console output.

Those NPEs are typical for missing resources.

The most common source for failing robolectric builds on different environmnets is probably robolectric not beeing able to load any resources.

Since robolectric needs to know where your Android Manifest is, you may have to provide a extra robolectric.properties for the build

http://robolectric.org/configuring/

Comment: I tried to run the build from jenkins console too. it was giving me some null pointer exception for test, I will put the errors in my question.

Comment: Changed answer a bit. Would be good to know what the failinig lines look like. (e.g. ConfigurationFragmentTest:36)

Comment: I looked into the logs and I did not found such warning as you mentioned. the line 36 is                                                                                        activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(HomeActivity.class);

Comment: Well, that line can't cause a NPE. You should probably check this again or there are parts of the trace missing.
How did you setup the project? Do you have the test classes within the same project as your main app?

Comment: yes, I created test classes in same project,in src folder with same packaging structure.

Comment: Also if my code have some errors than it should show some  consistency in failing test cases, like on every build it should show 2 test cases failed, rather giving random number of test case failed.

Comment: It could be a race condition. But like i said: the line you have given can't cause a NPE. It is not possible to guess what is causing the error without seeing the failing line(s) or the context of it

Comment: Okay...! I will share the test file with you